# Poor performance on SVG mouseover

Tags: reactjs

My code is much laggier than an example that I'm copying and I can't figure out why.

I'm trying to redo a page that is vanilla JS + [d3](https://d3js.org/) into React + VX. [VX](https://vx-demo.now.sh/) is a library that wraps d3 to make it fit react programming patterns. There are others like it, such as [Recharts](http://recharts.org/).

My problem comes when I add a mouseover callback that draws a vertical line at the x position of the mouse cursor.

I am following [this example](https://vx-demo.now.sh/areas), which is very smooth. You can see that as you move your cursor over the chart, the line follows smoothly.

To the best of my ability, I have done the same thing, but on my chart the line which follows the cursor is super laggy.

And it's not just the drawing of the line. I output the X position in the DOM as a sanity check, and that seems to update at the same laggy intervals.

The UI updates are laggy, even though I can tell that the mouseover callback is being called continuously and quickly on mouse move because I can see the console.log outputs come out much faster.

Here is my code. I'm wondering: why would mine be so much slower than the example I'm copying?

```
import React from 'react';
import rawData from 'lib/data.js';
import ChartData from 'lib/chart-data.js';
import { extent } from 'd3-array';
import { AxisLeft, AxisBottom } from '@vx/axis';
import { Group } from '@vx/group';
import { scaleTime, scaleLinear } from '@vx/scale';
import { Line, LinePath, Bar } from '@vx/shape';
import { localPoint } from '@vx/event';
import styles from './BitcoinPrice.scss';

const chartDimensions = (() => {
  const margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 35, left: 75 };
  const width = 800;
  const height = 400;
  const innerWidth = width - margin.left - margin.right;
  const innerHeight = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  return { margin, width, height, innerWidth, innerHeight };
})();

class BitcoinPrice extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      lineX: 0,
      lineVisible: false,
    };

    this.chartData = new ChartData(rawData);
  }

  onMouseOver() {
    this.setState({ lineVisible: true });
  }

  onMouseOut() {
    this.setState({ lineVisible: false });
  }

  onMouseMove(e, data, xScale) {
    const { margin } = chartDimensions;
    const point = localPoint(e);
    const x = point.x - margin.left;

    console.log(`x`, x);

    this.setState({ lineX: x });
  }

  render() {
    const { data } = this.chartData;
    const { margin, width, height, innerWidth, innerHeight } = chartDimensions;

    const xScale = scaleTime({
      range: [0, innerWidth],
      domain: extent(data, (d) => d.date)
    });

    const yScale = scaleLinear({
      range: [innerHeight, 0],
      domain: extent(data, (d) => d.price)
    });

    const lineX = this.state.lineX;
    const lineVisibility = this.state.lineVisible ? 'visible' : 'hidden';

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Example chart: Bitcion price over time</h1>
        <p>Mouse X position: {lineX}</p>

        <svg width={800} height={400} viewBox={`0 0 ${width} ${height}`}>
          <Group top={margin.top} left={margin.left}>
            {/* The bitcoin price line */}
            <LinePath
              data={data}
              x={(d) => xScale(d.date)}
              y={(d) => yScale(d.price)}
              className={`${styles['path-line']} ${styles['path-price']}`}
            />

            {/* The vertical line that follows the cursor when hovering */}
            <Line
              visibility={lineVisibility}
              x1={0}
              y1={0}
              x2={0}
              y2={innerHeight}
              transform={`translate(${lineX}, 0)`}
              className={styles['mouse-line']}
            />

            {/* Left axis */}
            <AxisLeft
              scale={yScale}
            />

            {/* Bottom axis */}
            <AxisBottom
              scale={xScale}
              top={innerHeight}
            />

            {/* Hover detection area */}
            <Bar
              width={innerWidth}
              height={innerHeight}
              className={styles['mouse-overlay']}
              onMouseOver={() => this.onMouseOver()}
              onMouseOut={() => this.onMouseOut()}
              onMouseMove={(e) => this.onMouseMove(e, data, xScale)}
            />
          </Group>
        </svg>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default BitcoinPrice;
```

Comment: I think your performance issues related to setState inside `mouseMove`, if you don't really need to setState in, then omit it and use `refs` instead to update the UI and values retrieval.

Comment: @mamounothman That worked - thank you! I posted updated code as an answer.

Comment: Glade it worked, accept your answer so that this question marked as answered.

Comment: Will do when I can 1 day from now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was to use refs instead of setState in the mouseMove callback. It seems like setState is not performant enough to be called every couple of milliseconds and expect to have the UI update without lag.

Note one VX-specific change: I had to change the `Line` component to a regular XML `line` tag, because in React, [refs are not supported on function components](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#refs-and-function-components).

Here's the updated code:

```
import React from 'react';
import rawData from 'lib/data.js';
import ChartData from 'lib/chart-data.js';
import { extent } from 'd3-array';
import { AxisLeft, AxisBottom } from '@vx/axis';
import { Group } from '@vx/group';
import { scaleTime, scaleLinear } from '@vx/scale';
import { Line, LinePath, Bar } from '@vx/shape';
import { localPoint } from '@vx/event';
import styles from './NeverLookBack.scss';

const chartDimensions = (() => {
  const margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 35, left: 75 };
  const width = 800;
  const height = 400;
  const innerWidth = width - margin.left - margin.right;
  const innerHeight = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  return { margin, width, height, innerWidth, innerHeight };
})();

class BitcoinPrice extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.lineRef = React.createRef();
    this.chartData = new ChartData(rawData);
  }

  onMouseOver() {
    this.lineRef.current.setAttribute('visibility', 'visible')
  }

  onMouseOut() {
    this.lineRef.current.setAttribute('visibility', 'hidden')
  }

  onMouseMove(e, data, xScale) {
    const { margin } = chartDimensions;
    const point = localPoint(e);
    const x = point.x - margin.left;

    console.log(`x`, x);

    this.lineRef.current.setAttribute('transform', `translate(${x}, 0)`)
  }

  render() {
    const { data } = this.chartData;
    const { margin, width, height, innerWidth, innerHeight } = chartDimensions;

    const xScale = scaleTime({
      range: [0, innerWidth],
      domain: extent(data, (d) => d.date)
    });

    const yScale = scaleLinear({
      range: [innerHeight, 0],
      domain: extent(data, (d) => d.price)
    });

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Example chart: Bitcion price over time</h1>

        <svg width={800} height={400} viewBox={`0 0 ${width} ${height}`}>
          <Group top={margin.top} left={margin.left}>
            {/* The bitcoin price line */}
            <LinePath
              data={data}
              x={(d) => xScale(d.date)}
              y={(d) => yScale(d.price)}
              className={`${styles['path-line']} ${styles['path-price']}`}
            />

            {/* The vertical line that follows the cursor when hovering */}
            <line
              ref={this.lineRef}
              x1={0}
              y1={0}
              x2={0}
              y2={innerHeight}
              className={styles['mouse-line']}
            />

            {/* Left axis */}
            <AxisLeft
              scale={yScale}
            />

            {/* Bottom axis */}
            <AxisBottom
              scale={xScale}
              top={innerHeight}
            />

            {/* Hover detection area */}
            <Bar
              width={innerWidth}
              height={innerHeight}
              className={styles['mouse-overlay']}
              onMouseOver={() => this.onMouseOver()}
              onMouseOut={() => this.onMouseOut()}
              onMouseMove={(e) => this.onMouseMove(e, data, xScale)}
            />
          </Group>
        </svg>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default BitcoinPrice;
```